# Add Additional Signatures to Template

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have created a simple webform that allows you a user to make some choices for a particular form.  Once they submit that data I then use a template, that I have already created through the Docusign UI, to burn that information onto the document.

My question is there could be from 1-4 signers on this document depending on some logic on my end.  So I was wondering would it be better to have these possible signers already laid out through the UI on the template or is there a way to add signers to a template/envelop dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do either. You can add new [signers via API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/update/) to the envelope that was created from the template, or you could have a template with [optional recipients](https://support.docusign.com/s/question/0D51W000069kA08SAE/optional-recipient-signer).
Pros of the latter is less API calls (additional one more API call to add new recipient(s)).
Pros of the former is more flexibility and ability to pretty much do whatever you want.
One more pro for the template approach is that you can set up your tabs via the web UI in advance. That may be a pro or a con depending on what your scenario is.
Are the document(s) always the same for you?